# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use foods.set() instead in django

Tags: python, django

I have this view:

```py
@login_required
def addmeal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addMeal(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request)
            return redirect('food:index')
    else:
        form = addMeal(user=request.user)      
    return render(request,'addmeal.html',{'form':form})
```

and this form:

```py
class addMeal(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'نام وعده'})
    )
    foods = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Food.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    )
    def save(self,request):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        meal = Meals(name=data['name'],user=request.user,foods=data['foods'])
        meal.save()
    def __init__(self, user=None,*args, **kwargs, ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['foods'].queryset = Food.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
            model = Meals
```

my models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Food(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155,default='')
    colorie = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    carbohidrat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cholestrol = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fiber = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    protein = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    saturatedfat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Meals(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(Food)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Diet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    meals = models.ManyToManyField(Meals)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

when i run server and fill out form and press submit django give me error(Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use foods.set() instead.).
what should i do to fix it?

Comment: error is clear you can not assign m2m values directly with object, by seeing your code may be `foods` is m2m and you are getting error in `Meals(name=data['name'],user=request.user,foods=data['foods'])`. Refer to - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Can you share your models.py?

Comment: You can not save the foods with `Meals(name=data['name'],user=request.user,foods=data['foods'])`. Is there a reason why you do not use a `ModelForm`? A `ModelForm` implements logic to handle m2m's, and will remove a large amount of boilerplate code.

Comment: dont work, what should i do?